# userena: no such table: userena_userenasignup

Tags: django

I am trying to get userena working for me and followed their documentation to set up the accounts app, URIs, etc.
I downloaded and installed userena just now, so it'll be the latest version. My django is version 1.5.1.

I did run manage.py syncdb and also started the accounts app -- the URIs are generated properly etc.

However, when filling in the sign up form and clicking submit, I get the following error:

```
DatabaseError at /accounts/signup/
no such table: userena_userenasignup
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/signup/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Value:    no such table: userena_userenasignup
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 362
```

Answer (score 1):

userena uses South to set up its database.

If you have South installed, simply run `./manage.py migrate userena`.

Comment: Cheers @Hamms. When I run your command I receive `Unknown command: 'migrate'`.

Comment: That means you don't have [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) installed. I'd recommend you do so!

Comment: Thanks again @Hamms. I did have South installed but hadn't added it to INSTALLED_APPS. Upon doing so, I can run `./manage.py migrate`, however I continue to see the same error message under the aforementioned conditions.

Comment: What was the output of the `./manage.py migrate` command? Did it migrate userena? Also, Is userena in INSTALLED_APPS?